# How to retrieve the Attribute Values into a class using LINQ?

Tags: xml, linq

This is a partial view of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<server xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" noNamespaceSchemaLocation="udsServerInfo.xsd" id="57672acc-4ba7-4876-811a-1629eca853ed" productPath="C:\Tools\ServerInfo\" osActivated="true">
  <networkAdapters>
    <networkAdapter id="6ad45274-6077-4a46-9b5c-d4e7be712310"...
```

I am able to retrieve all attribute values but not sure which method to use to grab each one ("productPath", "id",etc) into my class

```
    TextReader tr = new StringReader(xml);
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(tr);
    var server = from node in doc.Descendants("server").Attributes()
                    select new Server
                    {
                        serverId = node.???? <= need the attribute "id" here
                        serverProductPath = node. <= "productPath
                    };
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var servers = doc.Descendants("server")
    .Select(x=> new Server{id = x.Attribute("id").Value}).Tolist();
```

Comment: I don't get the method "Attribute". I only see "NextAttribute".

Comment: Notice I removed attributes from the query.  x is an XElement which has an Attribute method.